# How can I add a value to the beginning of a column for a select list without changing the column in the table?

Tags: sql, oracle

```
select display_value from (
    select
    FIRST_NAME || ' ' || LAST_NAME as display_value,
    case 
        when display_value is null then '<Not Assigned>' 
    end,
    UPPER(Number) as return_value,
    1 as ord
from team_members
where
    Number is not NULL
    and ANSWER = 'Y')
union all (
    select
    'Not Required' as display_value,
    'Not Required' as return_value,
    0 as ord
    from dual
) order by ord, display_value;
```

The expected output should be:

```
Not Assigned (if null)
Not Required
List of Names
```

This will be used for a select list with a save button which will update the table based on the selected value.
Any ideas?

Comment: Sample data and expected results would be useful. It isn't clear what you are trying to achieve. The 'full join' is maybe supposed to be union, to give some result when there are no matching rows? And the case expression looks like you wanted nvl or coalesce. But it's unclear, and the title says 'value at the beginning of a column', which .you don't seem to be doing at all.

Comment: A union might work. The goal to make a drop down select list with this query. The program I'm using will update the table when I hit a save button. When nothing is selected I want <Not Assigned> to display otherwise I want the display_value to show. The output should look like.
<Not Assigned>
Not Required
List of Names

Comment: I'm new to SQL so I'm sure my code is buggy

Comment: @AlexPoole I've edited my code based on your input. It's possible my code is too faulty to correct, but perhaps there's still a way to get my idea to work?

Comment: `union all` is the correct way to add boilerplate data to a result set. If you need to order in a specific way, add another column both to the result set and to the boilerplate extra: in the main `select`, add `, 1 as ord` at the end (with the comma, and the hardcoded 1, and the column name "ord"). In the second branch of `union all` add `, 0 as ord` to the end of `select`. And the ordering should be `order by ord, display_value`. This guarantees that the "boilerplate" values are shown before the actual result set, but otherwise the rows from the result set are still ordered by `display_value`

Comment: @mathguy I've updated my code based on your input. Now I'm getting an invalid identifier error for ord and display_value

Comment: You have several other syntax errors, I wasn't trying to fix them all. Get your query working without any ordering first; *then* add ordering, including the trick I showed you.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @mathguy this is the answer I came up with and it works.

```
SELECT T1.display_value 
  FROM (
       (
       SELECT tm.first_name || ' ' || tm.last_name as display_value,
              UPPER(tm.number) as return_value,
              1 as ord
         FROM team_members tm
        WHERE tm.number IS NOT null
          AND tm.bool = 'Y')
 UNION ALL (
       SELECT 'Not Required' as display_value,
              'Not Required' as return_value,
              0 as ord
         FROM dual)
 ORDER BY ord, display_value) T1
```

The software has a built in function to display a null value, so I didn't have to make a case for null values in the first place.